# How to look up something in a lookup table when there are two variables that change

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

Quick question-

I know this is probably really easy, but my excel skills have gotten a bit rusty. You can see from my picture below what my situation is. I have a table as a reference that shows something's priority based on its importance and how much work it takes. I will have hundreds of things I need to compare to this table. How can I fill out the question marks under the orange priority label quickly and easily? I could do an IF statement, but that would be like 300 lines long. I know a VLOOKUP won't work because there are too many variables.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=INDEX($the_data_part_of_the_reference_table,
       MATCH(current_importance_value, $importance_column_header_in_the_table, 0),
       MATCH(current_AoW_value,        $AoW_header_row_in_the_table,           0)
 )
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a matter of about a minute. :P

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT an identifier in the reference table and use VLOOKUP in the target table - searching for the identifier.